# how to load documents when needed in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In my meteor app I have a couple of publish/subscribe setup. Now I need to have an other for all users in the system. Now I don't need this information all the time, only when the user opens the configuration overlay. What is the preferred way to load the data on a specific user action (click on a button for example).

I'm also wondering about pagination, in case the number of users is huge, is something like this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use `Meteor.call()`

http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_call

You declare `Meteor.call` on the client and the method on the server. You can return any data you want,

```
// client
Meteor.call('getData', function(error, data) {
    // do something with data
})

// server
Meteor.methods({
    getData: function() {
        // return some data
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For pagination, look into using the Reactive Tables package on Atmosphere / Meteorite.